# How to make internal door map in c# with x y z coordinates

Tags: c#, indoor-map

I am saving x, y, and z geo coordinates from `gps` within a table in `sql server database` for movement history of things within my house\apartment

What I want to do is something like `Google map`, but with indoor map of my  house\apartment like for example... within my house\apartment where Something like TV is located and where it is moved
And drawing a line between those points based on the geo coordinates from `gps` saved in the database
So I got an image plan of my house\apartment and put it in `picturebox` and now ...

1. Is that good way to do it?
2. how I can treat image pixel xy coordinates as geo coordinates xy from gps ignoring the y axis because no need for height
3. Dose the bitmap image help?

I am really confused and lost on how to do it

Thanks for help

[image: on that diagram I waont to the above idea]

Comment: You want a graphic tools that has layer where you can put your room as a background and then add layers with info like x, y locations.  SVG is one format that uses XML format for the layers and the image can be any graphic format like GIF or JPG.

Answer (score 0):

> how I can treat image pixel xy coordinates as geo coordinates xy from gps ignoring the y axis because no need for height

You need to do some calibration. You will need to measure the gps position of at least two positions and mark these positions in your map. From there you should be able to compute a transformation between GPS positions and image coordinates. But you probably want to transform GPS coordinates to some local 'flat' coordinate system before doing the transformation to image coordinates.

But this plan might be more complicated than you realize. If you hope to be able to use your phone as the gps receiver I would be highly skeptical that you could be able to get any meaningful accuracy, the typical open sky accuracy is ~5m, and the indoor accuracy will be worse. Survey grade GPS can get down to centimeter accuracy, but will be expensive, more complicated to use, and if you are indoor you might need multiple reference transmitters outside your building.

A physical measurement tape seem far easier to use and much more accurate if the purpose is casual usage. There are also camera based systems that can give highly accurate local coordinates for (semi) professional usage. That is the typical solution for things like motion capture systems.